# What is the difference between [webview reload] and [webview loadRequest:(current URLRequest)]?

Tags: ios, webview, reload, difference

1. What is the difference between refreshing a webview by reload function and calling loadRequest for the same urlRequest?
2. What whould be faster to load a same webpage between using reload function and loadRequest function?